# Rules setup for Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I need to setup a rule on the drupal commerce with the following condition.

If Authenticated user added an item in cart and they didn't do the checkout for 24 hours, the site needs to shoot an email to the user with the cart content after 24 hours but only once, dont need to spam in every 24 hours.

How to perform this using rules? Any ideas Champs!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the  [Commerce Order Reminder](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/eternallight/2486393). It can help you!!

> As the name implies, this light weighted module sends email reminders to website users of the orders that were left uncompleted. The reminders will only be sent about those orders that have the email property filled. This includes even those orders of anonymous users that entered their email in the billing information form but did not complete the checkout process.

Comment: Thanks, i wil try this. It seems okey but in sandbox mode